# How to get country wise / timezone wise date & time from internet server

Tags: c#, datetime

i have to show date & time to user as per the user timezone id. i can not rely on user pc date time and setting. i was searching Google for the way and got a below code. code seems will query many external server for date & time but one thing not clear to me what kind of date & time i can expect from the below code.

some time i need india time. some time i need london time and some time i need other country local time. few county has many timezone that is why i want to send timezone id/name and want to get datetime based on timezone id/name.

so just guide me how to customize the below code where i can send user's side timezone id and routine will return right local time based on timezone id even if user pc datetime setting is wrong. looking for good help. thanks

```
public static DateTime GetFastestNISTDate()
{
    var result = DateTime.MinValue;

    // Initialize the list of NIST time servers
    // http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi
    string[] servers = new string[] {
        "nist1-ny.ustiming.org",
        "nist1-nj.ustiming.org",
        "nist1-pa.ustiming.org",
        "time-a.nist.gov",
        "time-b.nist.gov",
        "nist1.aol-va.symmetricom.com",
        "nist1.columbiacountyga.gov",
        "nist1-chi.ustiming.org",
        "nist.expertsmi.com",
        "nist.netservicesgroup.com"
};

        // Try 5 servers in random order to spread the load
        Random rnd = new Random();
        foreach (string server in servers.OrderBy(s => rnd.NextDouble()).Take(5))
        {
            try
            {
                // Connect to the server (at port 13) and get the response
                string serverResponse = string.Empty;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(server, 13).GetStream()))
                {
                    serverResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                // If a response was received
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverResponse))
                {
                    // Split the response string ("55596 11-02-14 13:54:11 00 0 0 478.1 UTC(NIST) *")
                    string[] tokens = serverResponse.Split(' ');

                    // Check the number of tokens
                    if (tokens.Length >= 6)
                    {
                        // Check the health status
                        string health = tokens[5];
                        if (health == "0")
                        {
                            // Get date and time parts from the server response
                            string[] dateParts = tokens[1].Split('-');
                            string[] timeParts = tokens[2].Split(':');

                            // Create a DateTime instance
                            DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(
                                Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[0]) + 2000,
                                Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[2]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[1]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[2]));

                            // Convert received (UTC) DateTime value to the local timezone
                            result = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime();

                            return result;
                            // Response successfully received; exit the loop

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore exception and try the next server
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

### EDIT

```
    var wc = GetFastestNISTDate();

    var pattern = InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var parseResult = pattern.Parse(wc.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    if (!parseResult.Success)
        throw new InvalidDataException("...whatever...");
    var instant = parseResult.Value;

    var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
    var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(timeZone);
    var bclDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
```

timezone translation is not working. i got the right date from this function `GetFastestNISTDate();` and next i try to get local date and time of different timezone based on my first utc time but code return wrong time for London. i guess i am making mistake the code. can anyone see & help. thanks

Comment: Note the `TimeZoneInfo` class as well, might save you on a web call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeservers will report UTC time (that's why the variable is named `utcDateTime`).

The `result = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime();` line converts that UTC time from the timeserver to the local time according to the timezone your computer is in. If you want a different timezone, you need to change that line.

As amit mentioned, you can use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx) to convert to some specified timezone. See the example on that page.

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```

Comment: thanks for reply.i was working with NodaTime library and it takes zoneid like "Asia/Kolkata", "Europe/London". just tell me can i use Nodatime library along with the above code.

Comment: my main motto is i should get right date & time even if user change his date & time.

Comment: @Mou Yes, you can use NodaTime to do the timezone translation.

Comment: i saw routine is giving right time GetFastestNISTDate() but do not understand on what basis it fetch datetime. i am not sending any timezone info or country code. so how the above routine is giving right time. please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime tzDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, TimeZone);
```

Hope this helps.