# How to change the day and Time as per User Timezone

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I do have a requirement such as say if there is 8:00 am (Fri) in Chicago so the same time would be In Singapore as 9:00 pm (Fri) as the day remains the same but if the timing in Chicago is 8:00 pm (Fri) the same timing would be in Singapore as 9:00 am (Sat).

The date change I am able to do by using the following function in SQL

```
dateadd(mi, 840, dateadd(hh, -1, '2015-01-30 08:00:00.000')
```

Where 840 is offset timing for Singapore and -1 is tzAdjust and 2015-01-30 08:00:00.000 is Datetime in Chicago
But how to convert the day as above I am not getting that.

Comment: Check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312639/how-to-get-country-wise-timezone-wise-date-time-from-internet-server/27313209#27313209

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
DECLARE
     @TimeHere DATETIME2(3)
    ,@OffsetMinutes INT

SELECT
     @TimeHere = GETDATE()
    ,@OffsetMinutes = 840

SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE,@OffsetMinutes,@TimeHere)    AS TimeThere
```